# How to separate Unit Tests and Integration Tests for different levels of maven lifecycle

Tags: maven, maven-2, integration-testing, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

Here is my plugin configuration from pom.xml file

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>run-unit-tests</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <skipITs>true</skipITs>
      <skipUTs>false</skipUTs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>run-integration-tests</id>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <skipITs>false</skipITs>
      <skipUTs>false</skipUTs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I have 2 test classes `HelloTest.java` and `WorldITest.java`.

When I run `mvn clean test` i want it to execute only **HelloTest**. But when i execute `mvn clean integration-test`, then I want both **HelloTest** and **WorldITest** to be executed.

But the problem is that it executes the Integration test also in `mvn clean test` command.

PS: Original code was taken from the discussion : [Prevent unit tests in maven but allow integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612344/prevent-unit-tests-in-maven-but-allow-integration-tests)

Comment: Your ITs are not correctly named, should be `WorldIT`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37999965/1743880 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5090311/1743880

Comment: @Tunaki thanks. That was the issue. You can add it as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get my Maven Integration tests to run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399240/how-do-i-get-my-maven-integration-tests-to-run)